# Showing prefix code for phone numbers - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented **jQuery International Telephone Input** but the issue now is, when i select the country, the prefix code doesn't show. How can i achieve this please ?

**View**

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="eventRegInput2">Phone Number</label>
   <input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control square" placeholder=""  value="{{ old('phone') }}"name="phone" required>
 </div>
```

JS code responsible for displaying the prefix of the country selected.

**JS**

```
// get the input val, adding the dial code if separateDialCode is enabled
_getFullNumber: function() {
  var val = $.trim(this.telInput.val()), dialCode = this.selectedCountryData.dialCode, prefix, numericVal = this._getNumeric(val), // normalized means ensure starts with a 1, so we can match against the full dial code
      normalizedVal = numericVal.charAt(0) == "1" ? numericVal : "1" + numericVal;
  if (this.options.separateDialCode) {
    prefix = "+" + dialCode;
  } else if (val.charAt(0) != "+" && val.charAt(0) != "1" && dialCode && dialCode.charAt(0) == "1" && dialCode.length == 4 && dialCode != normalizedVal.substr(0, 4)) {
    // if the user has entered a national NANP number, then ensure it includes the full dial code / area code
      prefix = dialCode.substr(1);
  } else {
    prefix = "";
  }
  return prefix + val;
},
```

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: You can set event handler onBlur on the text box and whenever user type and leave input you can check code and prefix it with country code by getting value and adding country code.

Comment: @MirkoAcimovic, the JS code above is suppose to return `prefix + val`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your function is working (that format properly input text with area code, all you have to do is when user leave textbox you can call your function to format number. This snippet need also to check if user has input something in textbox and if it is a valid code. Apart from that this is the way to ensure that your format function run everytime user leaves textbox and update its value with output from your function.

```
$('#phone').on('blur', function() {
       var value = $(this).val();      
       if(value) {
            $(this).val(_getFullNumber());
       }
});
```